# Ambiguous tag: [helix]

Tags: discussion, ambiguous-tags

There are currently 16 questions with this tag, but not all of them use it to mean the same thing.

These refer to the Helix 3D Toolkit for .NET (Suggestion: Create new tag [helix-3d-toolkit] and retag these(I would, but don't have enough reputation)):

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15677357/changing-model3dgroup-associated-to-model3d-with-helix-3d-toolkit
- [Enhance 3D kinect render performance inside a WPF application with Helix 3d Toolikt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597597/enhance-3d-kinect-render-performance-inside-a-wpf-application-with-helix-3d-tool)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356055/why-does-zoom-break-animation
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709488/intersection-of-an-stl-object-and-plane3d-using-wpf-3d-and-helix-toolkit
- [How to import a 3D model in WPF using Helix Toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295195/how-to-import-a-3d-model-in-wpf-using-helix-toolkit)
- [Porting Solar Wind XNA example to Helix 3d WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857259/porting-solar-wind-xna-example-to-helix-3d-wpf)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13144481/c-sharp-wpf-helix-scale-based-mesh-parenting-using-transform3dgroup
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310481/using-datatemplates-in-wpf-with-helixtoolkit-objects

These might have the same meaning as above:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490749/wpf-help-in-3ds-model

These use it to mean the Helix Navigation Framework([Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/dphill/silverlight-navigation-part-1)):

- [Silverlight helix code-behind page navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543602/silverlight-helix-code-behind-page-navigation)

These use it to mean RealMedia Helix server:

- [How to record a video directly on Helix Server from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15104451/how-to-record-a-video-directly-on-helix-server-from-my-android-device)
- [Helix Server - Unable to see segmented files in IPhone folder during stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587143/helix-server-unable-to-see-segmented-files-in-iphone-folder-during-stream)
- [How to stream Audio from Helix Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3719006/how-to-stream-audio-from-helix-server)
- [How can I stream cross-platform video without using RealServer (Helix) and Real Player?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241328/alternatives-to-realserver-helix-and-real-player)

These use it to mean the Helix DNA server(https://helix-server.helixcommunity.org/):

- [creating mobile streaming server (3gp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580392/creating-mobile-streaming-server-3gp)

These use it to mean the helix shape:

- [Rendering a toroidal helix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223115/rendering-a-toroidal-helix)

Comment: Relevant post on MSO: [Should the \[helix\] tag be split, or removed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/418327)